# Discord.py how to load messages sent before bot loaded

Tags: discord.py

So I had just finished making a message logging bot for a server, but I encountered a problem:
when I edit/delete a message that was sent before the bot had started it will not acknowledge the change. Is it possible to load in previous messages so on_message_edited() or on_message_deleted() will detect changes to all messages(even if it's just more recent ones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_message_delete(message)` and `on_message_edit(before, after)` are event handlers. Both events requires the original message to be in the message cache since Discord doesn't provide the original message along with the WebSocket event.

If the original message isn't in the cache, there's no way for your bot to know the content of the original message, thus it's impossible for discord.py to forward these events.

However, if you don't care about the original message and you *just need to know* that the message with message-id was deleted or edited, then there's the [`on_raw_message_delete(payload)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_delete) and [`on_raw_message_edit(payload)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_edit) events which triggers regardless if the message was found in cache but it contains no information about the original message prior to deleting/editing.